# Insert tweet search result in mongodb with python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, twitter

I'm trying to insert tweet search results into MongoDB using following code:

```
import json
import tweepy

from pymongo import MongoClient

ckey = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token_key = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(ckey, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

for data in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q='test',since='2015-08-01',until='2015-08-10').items():
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = client['twitter_db']
    collection = db['twitter_collection']
    tweet_json = json.loads(data)
    collection.insert(tweet_json)
```

But I got error message while parsing results as JSON:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_past.py", line 28, in <module>
    tweet_json = json.loads(data)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Any idea for inserting the good stuff in my JSON format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your cursor doesn't return you a JSON. It returns instances of `tweepy.models.Status` model. And it obviously can't be parsed as JSON.

To get parsed JSON from the model you can use `data._json`.

Comment: thanks using : collection.insert(data._json) it's working